# IBM Integration Bus XSL Transform node not generating XML

Tags: xslt, ibm-integration-bus

I am pretty new to IIB. I am creating a mediation service on IBM Integration Bus 10. First node is SOAP node and second node is an XSL transform. [Complete flow of the service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNXXI.jpg)

XSL transform is working fine with my SOAP input when I test it in a different tool. But it fails here when I am testing from soapui. After Transform node, I am getting the output without XML tags (all values appended in single string)

I have no clue why it is happening. Any help is well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
I am getting the output without xml tags (all values appended in single string)
```

IIB will not assume that the output of an XSLTransform node is XML. An XSL stylesheet can output formatted text. So you must set the 'Domain' property in the 'Output message parsing' section of the XSLTransform node. Set it to XMLNSC, obviously.

```
First node is SOAP node and second node is xsl transform
```

Is there a particular reason why you have chosen to use the XSLTransform node? A  Mapping node or a Compute node will perform better, and will be more maintainable than XSL (unless you are doing some genuinely complex transformations in XSL).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to see what is the version of the XSLT. If it is 2.0, XSL Transform Node is not supporting it. Try to rewrite it in XSLT version 1.0.